# How to restore ubuntu Linux to the default factory state/settings

Tags: ubuntu, restore

Hello I was wondering if Linux (Ubuntu) has a way of restoring the system if something goes wrong like a Microcomputer software Windows Personal Computer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a backup feature in Ubuntu, which is not enabled by default. It's located in Settings -> Backup. You may need to configure the folders and where to keep the backup to suit your needs.

[image]